# How to look for particular lines in a file using Tcl

Tags: linux, shell, tcl, tclsh

I have 2 files with similar contents and want to extract certain lines from each file and compare their values.
The lines that I am interested in are as an example :

First file :

```
11 stringABC /dir/path/to/stringABC 
20 stringXYZ /dir/path/stringXYZ
```

Second File:

```
13 stringABC /dir/path/of/secondFile/stringABC
151 stringXYZ /dir/path/stringXYZ
25  stringabc /dir/path/to/stringabc
```

Once i can recognize such lines in both the files i would compare the paths of stringABC and stringXYZ. Output would show a difference of path for stringABC whereas it matches for stringXYZ and missing entry in first file for stringabc.

i am using regexp to look for patterns that start with some digits followed by some string and then paths to directories.

```
First :  "{^(\d)*}"
Second: "[a-z]"
Third : "{(^/)}"`
```

Need to combine all three of these and catch such lines.

Comment: Please show us the code you've written to try to solve this problem, and explain specifically where you're having problems.

Comment: I have this right now which does not work : regexp -all -- "^{(\d) (a-z) (/)}" $line

Comment: The question I am having is how do i separate all these three matches ? Via a space or something else.

Comment: most reg-exs seem to honor the `|` char (`or`) for such patterns, BUT I have no significant experience with `tcl`. Try it. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `regexp`, try the `scan` command:

```
set line "25  stringabc /dir/path/to/stringabc"
if {[llength $line]==3 && [scan $line "%d %s %s" num str path] == 3} {
    if {[string match /* $path]} {
        # Do something with $num, $str, $path
    }
} else {
    # The line didn't start with an integer followed by two strings
}
```

Using `scan` is generally easier to use than `regexp` but is not as robust in case your possible lines may include something unexpected.

The following regexp will match exactly an integer, followed by an alphanumeric string, and concluding with a path name.

```
if {[regexp {^(\d+) +(\w+) +([[:alnum:]/]+$)} $l -> num str path] == 1} {
    # This matches.  Do something with $num, $str and $path
}
```

Comment: Thanks for recommending scan , it works but also catches lines which has : for example (11: /path/to/dir) and this should come to else part.

Comment: I updated my answer to include a check for `llength`.

Comment: thanks that worked, now creating 2 dictionaries to store $str and $path as key value pairs to compare with each other.

Comment: Do you think scan is robust enough and i dont regex to capture the data ?

Comment: No.  scan is not as robust as regexp, but it's very good when you don't have unexpected values to match.   I updated my answer to include a regexp.